# How do I get the doctrine entity column name for translations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation

Exaple: mysql_table

[image]

Example twig file
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're need to use twig's [`attribute`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function:

```
{{ attribute(gender, 'gender' ~ app.request.locale|capitalize) }}
```

However, better solution is to use specialized tool, e.g. [JMSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle)